# いつものようにマージエディタが開かないのになぜかHEADがたくさんあります。どう解決すればいいですか？

Tags: git

`rails s` のエラーでgemfile.lockのコンフリクトを直せと出たので、開いたら「現在の変更のままにする」と修正したはずがまたHEADと出て、マージエディタも表示されないので解決できません。心折れます。
ChatGPTに頼ってもダメです。
どうすればコンフリクト解決できますか？

一応railsアプリフォルダのgithubです。↓

https://github.com/Noob-9191/RAILS-dedicated-to-public/commit/d33fddcbd7072d1209cf0ede56c62e3bddc2a966

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

マージエディタすらないのにどうやってこのコンフリクトを解決しろっていうのでしょうか？

Comment: `gemfile.lock` をバージョン管理ツールの対象にしちゃったってこと？ `gemfile.lock` は `bundle install` が作成する成果物なので、バージョン管理に入れちゃダメっス。コンフリクトして当然。 `bundle update` で再生成できるはずなので試してください。今オイラん手元に `ruby` 環境ないので試せないっス。

Answer (score 2):

> マージエディタすらないのにどうやってこのコンフリクトを解決しろっていうのでしょうか？

まずはじめに、お使いのエディタであるVS Codeにはグラフィカルにmerge conflictを修正できる機能があります。

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_merge-conflicts

commit logを拝見させていただきましたが、どうやらstashに保存した変更をpopする時にconflictしてしまったのではないかと思います。が、一度commitしてしまった以上はVS Codeのconflict解決支援機能を使うのは難しいようなので、がんばって手で修正するか、あるいはまた最初からrails newをし直してみるというが一番近道なのではないでしょうか。

また、Railsアプリケーション開発においては、Gemfile.lockもcommitしてバージョン管理の対象にすることが通常の開発方法です。理由は、アプリケーションの運用においては、どの環境においても全てのライブラリのバージョンを揃えておくことが重要なためです。Gemfile.lockはそのためにbundlerが自動で作成するファイルです。

全ての環境において使用するライブラリのバージョンを揃えるのは、bundle installのタイミングで新しいバージョンのライブラリが公開されていた、などの理由で開発環境と本番環境で異なるバージョンのライブラリがインストールされてしまった結果、ライブラリの挙動が変わってしまったことなどによる不具合を起こさないようにするためです。